# Como mostrar ceros a la izquierda de un numero binario en java?

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy tratando de convertir un numero hexadecimal en binario y contar las posiciones en las que se encuentran los 1, pero al momento de hacerlo, no me muestra los 0 de lado izquierdo, por lo cual la posición se ve afectada.

Por ejemplo, tengo el numero hexadecimal **28C28805**, al convertirlo en binario me queda asi ***00*10 1000 1100 0010 1000 1000 0000 0101** pero al ejecutar el programa me muestra este resultado **10 1000 1100 0010 1000 1000 0000 0101** donde omite los dos primeros 00.

Existe alguna manera de mostrar esos dígitos que por lógica no muestra?

Anexo el código con el que trabajo actualmente:

```
package examenbitmap;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class ExamenBitmap {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Ingrese el bit primario: ");
        String hex = bf.readLine();


       System.out.println("Ingrese el bit secundario: ");

       String hexa = bf.readLine();

        int y = Integer.parseInt(hex,16);
        int x = Integer.parseInt(hexa,16);

        String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(y);
        String binx= Integer.toBinaryString(x);

        String biny= Integer.toBinaryString(y) + Integer.toBinaryString(x);

        System.out.println("El valor del bitmap primario es: "  + biny);
        //System.out.println("El valor del bitmap secundario es: " + binx);
        System.out.println("Posicion de cada uno en la cadena: ");

        for(int i=0;i<biny.length();i++){
            if ('1'==biny.charAt(i)) {
                if (i>0){
                    System.out.print(",");
                }
                System.out.print(String.valueOf(i+1));
            }
        }
            System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para convertir de Hexadecimal a Binario, puedes usar mejor la clase [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), pues si usas `Integer` tendrás problemas con los valores de más de 32 bits. Para usarlo es necesario importar la clase.

Para obtener una cadena fija de 32 posiciones, puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
String valor32=String.format("%32s", valor).replace(" ", "0");
```

Te dejo un ejemplo con ambas posibilidades.

Ejemplo: **[`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/HVTXU71425)**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;


class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

          String s="28C28805";

          String valorInt=hexToBinaryI(s);
          System.out.println(valorInt);

          //32 bits
          String valorInt32=String.format("%32s", valorInt).replace(" ", "0");
          System.out.println(valorInt32);

          String valorBigInt=hexToBinary(s);
          System.out.println(valorBigInt);

          //32 bits
          String valorBigInt32=String.format("%32s", valorBigInt).replace(" ", "0");
          System.out.println(valorBigInt32);       


    }

    //Usando BigInt
    public static String hexToBinary(String hex) 
    {
        return new BigInteger(hex, 16).toString(2);
    }


    //Usando Int
    public static String hexToBinaryI(String hex) 
    {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
        String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
        return binaryString;
    }

}
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
101000110000101000100000000101
00101000110000101000100000000101
101000110000101000100000000101
00101000110000101000100000000101
```

Comment: Me parece que su respuesta está extraída de una pregunta en inglés? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246326/convert-hexadecimal-string-hex-to-a-binary-string si es así sería bueno que también lo anexará a su respuesta. quizá me equivoque.

Comment: No exactamente @DarkFenix Mi fuente favorita es [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/ConvertBigIntegerintoanotherradixnumber.htm), no todo en la vida es Stackoverflow.

Comment: No sería ni el primero ni el ultimo en hacer esto. si fuese el caso, solo se parecen  las respuestas de aquella pregunta. me equivoqué entonces.+1

Comment: De este tipo de preguntas podría haber unas cuantas en SO en inglés, @DarkFenix Gracias por el +1.